# How to divide menus to left and right in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a navbar in bootstrap 3.x. But I have an issue ([JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ns82ne1z/)) when trying to divide the menus to the left and right as in the following example.

```
Home - About - Services - Contact                                           Login - Register
```

But the result I get with my code is something like this:

```
Home - About -                                                                     Login
Services - Contact                                                               Register
```

This is my code currently.

```css
.site-top-nav{
    padding:0.5em;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.site-top-nav li{
    margin-left: 2%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="nagivation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="navbar-inner site-top-nav">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li>Home</li>
          <li>About</li>
          <li>Services</li>
          <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="float:right;">
          <li>Login</li>
          <li>Register</li>
        </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

I have tried other methods, but I can't get the effect I needed.

Comment: Insted of use a style property ```style="float: right"```, you should use ```class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"```

see this example: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/

Comment: I updated your jsfiddle to help a little more: https://jsfiddle.net/ns82ne1z/1/

Comment: chk this --- https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_right&stacked=h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `float: left` property to other `ul` element, and `display: inline-block` to `li` element

try using this [Jsfiddle code updated](https://jsfiddle.net/ns82ne1z/2/)

Comment: This is not responsive

Comment: @ehsan what is design for responsive

Answer (score 3):

I did few changes to your existing fiddle.
Just you need to add one more css property 
check it here : https://jsfiddle.net/ns82ne1z/5/

`.navbar-nav li{
  margin-left:10px;
}`.

it may help you.

Comment: This is not responsive

Answer (score 0):

**Example below**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Basic Navbar Example</h3>
  <p>A navigation bar is a navigation header that is placed at the top of the page.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

If it helps mark as answer.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do something like the code I will link below:

```css
.body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.nav-bar {
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.nav-bar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-bar li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.left {
  position: relative;
  right: 30px;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="nav-bar">
      <ul>
        <li class="left">Home</li>
        <li class="left">About</li>
        <li class="left">Contact</li>
        <li class="left">More</li>
        <li class="right">Register</li>
        <li class="right">Log In</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hopefully this works for you, any issues please report back. It worked in the fiddle so it should apply the same to your project.

Best of luck mate!

Answer (score 0):

Editted on https://jsfiddle.net/ns82ne1z/4/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="navbar-inner site-top-nav">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Services</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li>Login</li>
      <li>Register</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Add in the following CSS

```
.site-top-nav li{
  padding-left:15px;
  padding-right:15px;
}

.navbar-nav>li {
    float: left;
}
```

Hope this helps.